# How do I properly run this systemd service on shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, systemd, unmount, google-drive

I am mounting my Google Drive on login using `google-drive-ocamlfuse`. The problem is that shutting down or rebooting now seems to have an added 2 minute pause.

Now if when I unmount the Google Drive prior to shutting down, everything goes the way it should and there is no pause.

I inspected some `systemd` services and built a new one without knowing exactly what I am doing ("educated guess").

`/etc/systemd/system/rs-shutdown.service`:

```
# Redsandro 2017-09-1 
# Unmount GoogleDrive to prevent shutdown delay.

[Unit]
Description=Unmount GoogleDrive on shutdown
Before=umount.target shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "umount /home/redsandro/GoogleDrive"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo systemctl enable rs-shutdown.service
sudo systemctl start rs-shutdown.service
```

However, shutdown is still lagging by 2 minutes. I still need to manually unmount the share if I want a fast shutdown.

Is there a solution, or is this simply the wrong place to try and do what I want?

I'm Running Linux Mint 17 and Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Comment: Does it unmount cleanly when you do it manually or do you need to close any applications first?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a simple service that performs a task before shutdown. Please note that the default dependencies are disabled by the `DefaultDependencies=no` option

```
[Unit]
Description=SleepBeforeShutdown Service
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 30
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target shutdown.target reboot.target
```

After creating/editing your service unit file run
`systemctl enable yourservice.service` and reboot.
(it is not necessary to run `systemctl start yourservice.service`). 
After that, any time you run shutdown, halt or reboot, the type-oneshot service will do its thing first and then the system proceeds with actual shutdown/reboot.

**Edit**
I've now found a previous [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/795406/980677) where the same solution was offered. I do not have the credits to post comments with a link to the question above, so I'll leave my answer as is (even though, strictly speaking, it's a duplicate) Moderators, please remove this post if it violates the rules.

**Edit 2**
And yet another old [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/how-to-run-a-script-with-systemd-right-before-shutdown/479048#479048) with the same answer. Really not that difficult to find ...