# ssh command on shutdown fails

Tags: ssh, shutdown

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server, I'm connecting to a UPS. I want the Ubuntu server to shut down a truenas server, also on the same ups. The idea is that the UPS software on Ubuntu server triggers the shutdown on the trunas server when the battery is at 50%, The ubuntu server in turn triggers a shutdown of the trunas server, giving time for both boxes to power down gracefully.

I've set up the following script file `truenas-off.sh`:

```
echo "shutdown occurred at $(date)" >> /root/shutdown-events.log
ssh root@1.2.3.4 "midclt call system.shutdown"
```

I set the script up [as described here](https://devicetests.com/ubuntu-script-logout-reboot-shutdown), the only difference is I set mine to just shutdown.

```
cat  /etc/systemd/system/truenas-off.service
[Unit]
Description=Run truenas-off on shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/root/truenas-off.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've run `ssh-keygen` on the ubuntu server and `ssh-copy-id root@truenas-IP` and when I've issued `sudo -i`, authenticated, I can `ssh root@trunasIP truenas-off.sh` and the trunas turns off

It just doesn't seem to want to work automatically when I shutdown the Ubuntu server.

What am I doing wrong?

There's a similar problem, but not quite the same here: [How to send shutdown command to servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977427/how-to-send-shutdown-command-to-servers/977429#977429)

Comment: The page you followed is incomplete. You are missing a few things in the `[unit]` section of the script that tells systemd to run the service at shutdown. By default the service will run when the system boots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly run this systemd service on shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952363/how-do-i-properly-run-this-systemd-service-on-shutdown)

Comment: In the script `truenas-off.sh` you have the command `ssh root@1.2.3.4 "midclt call system.shutdown"`. Does 1.2.3.4 stand for `trunasIP` that you use later? Why do you run this script from within the Trunas manually by `ssh root@trunasIP truenas-off.sh`. Does the script `truenas-off.sh` stored in the Ubuntu server or in the Truenas?

Comment: Please see the simpler second link the the duplicate question's answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41756/524752 Basically, just change "ExecStart" to "ExecStop". You can also look in `journalctl` to see if your service is running

Comment: @DanielT  `ExecStop=` allows running a command (or multiple commands) when the service is stopped, not necessarily when the computer is stopped. It is important to understand the nuances.